# How to send HTTP request with protocol buffers as the payload format?

Tags: java, junit, protocol-buffers

I am brand new to protocol buffers library.. I know how to send request and get response back from a web service using JSON as my payload format...But I do not know how to do the same with protobuf.

Can some one please help and list a small example?

Fmy my project , I want to send the following three things to the server:

```
{ 

    "session_id": "xxxxxx",
    "location": {
        "latitude": xx.xx,
        "longitude": xx.xx
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Where is the Java code you have so far? Would you share it?

Comment: Protobuf is just binary data. So there are two separate concerns here: a) how to serialize/deserialize your data to/from objects/binary, and b) how to send/receive binary over http. Which are you stuck on?

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for your reply.. I believe I need guidance on both parts.. All I have with me is request parameters and what response I would get from the server..Do you have any working examples that you cans share?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Javascript is not able to handle handle pure binary formats easy, which the wireformat in protobuffers is. You *can* just send the wireformat over HTTP, but it will probably be hard to deal with it on the client side.

So what you can do is to serialize and deserialize the protobuf message to JSON on the serverside and use that for transport between client and server. you can use https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/ to do these conversions in Java.

However, this library looks interesting, which seems to actually handle the binary wireformat in javascript: https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js